# How do I find if a specific NFT in a wallet is a Decentraland LAND NFT?

Tags: solidity, nft, smart-contract-wallets

Suppose I have a wallet, and a list of NFTs that wallet has. And I use something like the “balanceOf” function to check if that wallet contains a DCL Land NFT, and I find that the wallet does contain the land NFT.

If there are a 1000 different NFTs in that wallet, how do I find which one of those are the LAND NFTs? I’m working on a project, where I only want to show DCL Lands NFTs on the frontend which the user has in his/her wallet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the contract address of that particular NFT. Once you have that, you can filter out rest of the NFTs based on the contract address.